# How does FCM server identify the target device over the network?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

With FCM we use the firebase registration tokens to identify the devices. How does the FCM server know the IP of the device to whom it needs to send a message over a connection? For eg., if I am on a constant move and my IP keeps on changing, then the FCM server needs to know about it. Is there a service sitting inside my app has the responsibility of updating it? How does it actually happen? If possible please do provide a link to some reliable source explaining this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This action is performed by Google Play Services. This registers with the FCM servers, and then checks for messages for the device's Instance ID token.

Comment: You mean the device polls for messages from the FCM servers?